# No scrolling inside ListView UWP

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

In my uwp app I have a `ListView` but it's fixed height and not scrollable> I know there are many similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them helped me.
Here's my code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Reply.heading}"
                   FontSize="20"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Margin="10"/>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Reply.faq, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:FaqItem">
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind question, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                   FontSize="18"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind answer, Mode=OneWay}"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                   Margin="0, 0, 0, 20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Remove this `IsHitTestVisible="False"`.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling is not working because you're setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"` so, remove that line, And if you want a ListView with auto height, set `VerticalAllignment="Top"` as given below:

```
....
 <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Reply.faq, Mode=OneWay}"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Grid.Row="1">
....
```